# From Backend to Frontend Yii2 Advanced App

Tags: hyperlink, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to link some controllers from frontend to backend. After some hours I don't where could be the problem.

**Backend**

```
file: main.php

    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'baseUrl' => '/backend/web',
    ],        
    'urlManagerFrontEnd' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'baseUrl' => '/frontend/web',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ]


file: SiteController.php

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        // User's variable
        $user = \common\models\User::findIdentity(Yii::$app->user->id);

        if($user->role != self::USER_ADMIN){
            return $this->redirect(Url::to(Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createUrl(['/site/index'])));
        }

        return $this->render('index');
    }
```

Using this

> Url::to(Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createUrl(['/site/index']))

Returns me

> /advanced/backend/web/index.php?r=site%2Findex

Any advice?

Comment: @InsaneSkulll When I try to redirect to the Frontend, Yii says me 
 _Page not found_ . I'm stucked and I'd like to know how I could fix it

Comment: You don't need `Url::to()`

Comment: look at my solution to fix your problem.

Comment: Hello @JorgeBrage, please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. urlManagerFrontEnd should return url based on baseUrl `/frontend/web`.

Try change baseUrl to `http://yourdomain/`

Comment: I gues I have the problem because is hosted in localhost so, finallyI solved it in this way. `    const ROLE_ADMIN = 0;

    public function beforeAction($event) {
        // User's variable
        $user = \common\models\User::findIdentity(Yii::$app->user->id);
        if (is_null($user) == false) {
            if ($user->role == self::ROLE_ADMIN) {
                return $this->redirect(["site/logout"]);
            }
        }
        return parent::beforeAction($event);
    }    `

Answer (score 0):

I did little googling and found [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/60118-creating-links-from-backend-to-frontend-and-frontend-to-backend/page__view__findpost__p__268649).

for reference I am posting same here

> I read around in the UrlManager.php and found the following:

```
$baseUrl = $this->showScriptName || !$this->enablePrettyUrl ? $this->getScriptUrl() : $this->getBaseUrl();
```

> So this means when `showScriptName= true` and `enablePrettyUrl=false` `$baseUrl = getScriptUrl()` otherwise `$baseUrl = getBaseUrl()`
>
> So it just work with `prettyUrl=true` and the `showScriptName = false`. When we set prettyUrl on true it takes `$baseUrl = getBaseUrl()`
>   Changing it to the following it resolves our problem =).

```
/*$baseUrl = $this->showScriptName || !$this->enablePrettyUrl ? $this->getScriptUrl() : $this->getBaseUrl();*/

$baseUrl = !$this->showScriptName || $this->enablePrettyUrl ? $this->getScriptUrl() : $this->getBaseUrl();
```

> Now you have to set `prettyurl=false` and the other on true et voila

I tried this on a fresh template and then applied code you mentioned in question and got the same error as you got.

But then after the fix I did according to this post I get correct path.

[This link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1578) is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

in your frontend config add this to the top to define 2 variables.

```
use \yii\web\Request;
$baseUrl = str_replace('/frontend/web', '/frontend/web', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());
$backEndBaseUrl = str_replace('/frontend/web', '/backend/web', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());
```

And set these variables as the baseUrl parameters in the components

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        //'baseUrl' => '/frontend/web',
        'baseUrl'=> $baseUrl,
    ],
    'urlManagerBackEnd' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        //'baseUrl' => '/backend/web',
        'baseUrl' => $backEndBaseUrl,
    ],
```

then you can have links from the frontend to the backend by e.g.

```
$backendUrl= Yii::$app->urlManagerBackEnd->createUrl('//');
echo yii\helpers\Html::a('link to backend', $backendUrl);
```

to have the same from the backend to the frontend add this to the backend config:

```
use \yii\web\Request;
$baseUrl = str_replace('/backend/web', '/backend/web', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());
$frontEndBaseUrl = str_replace('/backend/web', '/frontend/web', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());
```

and in the components:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'baseUrl'=> $baseUrl,
    ],
    'urlManagerFrontEnd' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        //'baseUrl' => '/backend/web',
        'baseUrl' => $frontEndBaseUrl,
    ],
```

and to create links use:

```
$frontendUrl= Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createUrl('//');
echo yii\helpers\Html::a('link to frontend', $frontendUrl);
```

forgot you can of course also link to specific pages e.g. from backend to frontend site/about:

```
$frontendUrl= Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createUrl('/site/about');
echo yii\helpers\Html::a('link to frontend site about', $frontendUrl);
```

BTW. if you have removed the /web behavior by some htaccess you should also remove it in the variables.

Answer (score 0):

use this code. it will redirect you to front end

```
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('./../../frontend/web/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below one:

`Url::to(Yii::$app->urlManagerBackEnd->createUrl('index.php/'/site/index'), true);`