# yii2 - frontend to backend and backend to frontend controller config files + .htaccess - COMPLETLY CONFIGURATION

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2, frontend, backend

I'm trying to completely manage my page with `.htaccess` file and two links/button or redirect:

- one from frontend to backend
- one from backend to frontend

Hope that is clearly enough.

My environment is DEV as I'm working localy if that is so difference.

All I tried:

- https://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/60118-creating-links-from-backend-to-frontend-and-frontend-to-backend/
- [From Backend to Frontend Yii2 Advanced App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497350/from-backend-to-frontend-yii2-advanced-app)
- https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1578
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvMlc1lCOOo

And I'm a bit confused with `.htaccess` files and `urlManager` so appreciate any help a lot.

Let's check the files :

### DIRECTORY ROOT & COMMON

---

**/.htacces**

```
#prevent directory listing
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*

#follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ frontend/web
```

**/common/config/main.php**

```
  return [
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
    ],
];
```

### FRONTEND & FRONTEND CONTROLLER

---

**/frontend/.htacces**

```
RewriteEngine on

#if directory or a file exist, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#otherwise, forward to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**/frontend/config/main.php**

```
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        ],
        // main - used to generate and parse URLs to frontend from 
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'baseUrl' => '/frontend/web',
            'rules' => [
                '/' => 'site/index',
                'home' => 'site/home',
                'about' => 'site/about',
                'moje-prace' => 'site/moje-prace',
                'umow-wizyte' => 'rezerwacje/create',
                'contact' => 'site/contact',
                'login' => 'site/login',
                'signup' => '/site/signup',
            ],
        ],
// slave - used to generate URLs to backend from frontend app
        'urlManagerBackend' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
            'baseUrl' => '/admin',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ]

        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
            'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

**/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php**

```
namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm;
use frontend\models\ResetPasswordForm;
use frontend\models\SignupForm;
use frontend\models\ContactForm;

/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout', 'index', 'home', 'contact', 'about'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['index'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['home'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['contact'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['about'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {

            $this->layout = 'main';

            return $this->render('home');
        }

        return $this->goHome();
    }


    /**
     * Displays about page.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionHome()
    {
        return $this->render('home');
    }


    /**
     * Logs in a user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        $this->layout = 'welcome';

        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {

            $this->layout = 'main';

            return $this->render('home');
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {

            $this->layout = 'main';

            return $this->render('home');
        }
        else {
            $model->password = '';

            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs out the current user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }

    /**
     * Displays contact page.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {

            if ($model->sendEmail(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {

                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
            }
            else {

                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'There was an error sending your message.');
            }

            return $this->refresh();
        }
        else {
            return $this->render('contact', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays about page.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionAbout()
    {
        return $this->render('about');
    }

    /**
     * Signs user up.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionSignup()
    {

        $this->layout = 'welcome';

        $model = new SignupForm();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            if ($user = $model->signup()) {

                if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {

                    $this->layout = 'main';

                    return $this->actionHome();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('signup', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

### BACKEND & BACKEND CONTROLLER

---

**/backend/.htacces**

```
RewriteEngine on

#if directory or a file exist, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#otherwise, forward to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**/backend/config/main.php**

```
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'homeUrl' => '/administrator',
    'modules' => [],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
            'baseUrl' => '/administrator',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-backend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
            'name' => 'advanced-backend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
// main - used to generate and parse URLs to backend from backend app
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'baseUrl' => '/backend/web',
        ],
// slave - used to generate URLs to frontend from backend app
        'urlManagerFrontend' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'baseUrl' => '/',
            'rules' => [
                '/' => 'site/index',
                'home' => 'site/home',
                'about' => 'site/about',
                'moje-prace' => 'site/moje-prace',
                'umow-wizyte' => 'rezerwacje/create',
                'contact' => 'site/contact',
                'login' => 'site/login',
                'signup' => 'site/signup',
            ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

**/backend/controllers/SiteController.php**

```
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\LoginForm;

/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                        'allow' => true,
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    /**
     * Login action.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            $model->password = '';

            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logout action.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }
}
```

### VHOST & APACHE.CONF

---

**apache2.conf**

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/project>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**vhost**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@prst.app
    ServerName pp.test
    DocumentRoot /home/user/project/pp/

<Directory "/home/user/project/pp/">
    Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/pp__error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/pp_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I can not create the hyperlink in a view or redirect in controller from frontend to backend, and from backend to frontend.

Comment: In examples you've linked there are always two URL managers (separate for backend and fronted). Why you're using only one?

Comment: sorry too much code i cut off. fixed. thank you !

Comment: do i need this urlManager in common/main ?

Comment: you need to add the urlmanager configurations in `frontend/config/main.php` and `backend/config/main.php` separately rather than adding in the `common/config/main.php`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam fixed. Still not working after done steps below.

Comment: I am not sure how you followed the below answer, it **should** work correctly if you have followed and added correct `urlManager` configurations, can you update your question with the latest changes you have made ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam updated.

Comment: ok a few things i need to ask, you are not using virtual hosts atall and you are using the url like `http://localhost/my-app` ? and you want your app to work in a way if someone types in `http://localhost/my-app` he should be automatically redirected to `http://localhost/my-app/frontend/web` and if type in `http://localhost/my-app/admin` it should redirect to `http://localhost/my-app/backend/web` and you want to be able to create links to the `frontend` via `backend` and to `backend` via `frontend` ? is it correct ?

Comment: I'm using virtual hosts with different path than var/www/html, so i'm not strictly use http://localhost/my-app but instead of this i'm using http://site.test/ and this should be redirected to frontend, but i other side http://site.test/admin should be redirected to the backend, that's all i need to do, i thought it shouldn't be hard to do with framework...

Comment: if you are using virtual host then can you add the configuration, as per docs you already map the `frontend/web` directory to `site.test` and htaccess for the root directory is out of the context as when you type `site.test` you are in `frontend/web` directory so technically if you donot want to map another virtual host then you should modify the `.htaccess` inside of `frontend/web` directory, can you please add your virtual host configurations.

Comment: ummm into the question please , it isnt readable here

Comment: forgot about it. added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's done ! On the fresh yii2 advanced i set up connections between frontend and backend, but still have a problem with pretty url in both "sides".

**backend/.htaccess**

---

```
RewriteEngine on

#if directory or a file exist, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#otherwise, forward to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**backend/config/main.php**

---

```
use \yii\web\Request;
$baseUrl = str_replace('/backend/web', '/backend/web', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());
$frontEndBaseUrl = str_replace('/backend/web', '/frontend/web', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());

$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
        ],

'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-backend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],

        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
            'name' => 'advanced-backend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],


// main - used to generate and parse URLs to backend from backend app
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'baseUrl' => '/backend/web',
        ],
// slave - used to generate URLs to frontend from backend app
        'urlManagerFrontend' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'baseUrl' => '/',
            'rules' => [
                '/' => 'site/index',
                'home' => 'site/home',
                'about' => 'site/about',
                'moje-prace' => 'site/moje-prace',
                'umow-wizyte' => 'rezerwacje/create',
                'contact' => 'site/contact',
                'login' => 'site/login',
                'signup' => 'site/signup',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

### backend links for frontend

simply created with:

```
$frontendUrl= Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontend->createUrl('//');
echo yii\helpers\Html::a('link to frontend', $frontendUrl);
```

**frontend/.htaccess**

---

```
RewriteEngine on

#if directory or a file exist, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#otherwise, forward to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**frontend/config/main.php**

---

```
use \yii\web\Request;
$baseUrl = str_replace('/frontend/web', '/frontend/web', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());
$backEndBaseUrl = str_replace('/frontend/web', '/backend/web', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());


$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
            'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],

// main - used to generate and parse URLs to frontend from frontend app
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
            'rules' => [
                '/' => 'site/index',
                '/home' => 'site/home',
                '/about' => 'site/about',
                'moje-prace' => 'site/moje-prace',
                'umow-wizyte' => 'rezerwacje/create',
                'contact' => 'site/contact',
                'login' => 'site/login',
                'signup' => '/site/signup',
            ],
        ],
// slave - used to generate URLs to backend from frontend app
        'urlManagerBackend' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
            'baseUrl' => $backEndBaseUrl,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],

    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

### frontend links for backend

simply created with:

```
$backendUrl= Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl('//');
echo yii\helpers\Html::a('link to backend', $backendUrl);
```

In the root directory what means http://localhost/app-name/ i created index.php file for redirecting to frontend while clicking link on backend (to frontend):

**/index.php**

---

```
header("Location: http://pp.test/frontend/web/", true, 301);
exit();
```

And by now it works so so, but i'm not able to enable pretty url in the backend as it does not works corectlly. And also i do not think that's a good way using redirecting from other file especially from root directory.

Please note, that in common/config/main.php no changes is needed and do not need .htaccess file in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your frontend is at `http://localhosts` and your backend at `http://localhosts/admin`. If your rewrite rules does not work correctly, you may try [use symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49826324/5812455) for this - at least for me it was always simpler and less problematic way of handling frontend/backend URLs on shared hosting.

---

You always have 2 `UrlManager` components: main  (for current environment) and slave (for second environment, for example for backend in frontend app). So in `frontend/config/main.php` you will have something like:

```
// ...
// main - used to generate and parse URLs to frontend from frontend app
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'baseUrl' => '/',
    'rules' => [
        '/' => 'site/index',
        'home' => 'site/home',
        'about' => 'site/about',
        'moje-prace' => 'site/moje-prace',
        'umow-wizyte' => 'rezerwacje/create',
        'contact' => 'site/contact',
        'login' => 'site/login',
        'signup' => 'site/signup',
    ],
],
// slave - used to generate URLs to backend from frontend app
'urlManagerBackend' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
    'baseUrl' => '/admin',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
],
// ...
```

And in `backend/config/main.php`:

```
// ...
// main - used to generate and parse URLs to backend from backend app
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'baseUrl' => '/admin',
],
// slave - used to generate URLs to frontend from backend app
'urlManagerFrontend' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'baseUrl' => '/',
    'rules' => [
        '/' => 'site/index',
        'home' => 'site/home',
        'about' => 'site/about',
        'moje-prace' => 'site/moje-prace',
        'umow-wizyte' => 'rezerwacje/create',
        'contact' => 'site/contact',
        'login' => 'site/login',
        'signup' => 'site/signup',
    ],
],
// ...
```

As you can see, they're swapped - main `UrlManager` from frontend app is slave in backend app. Depending on current and target environment, you're using different URL manager.

If you want to generate URL to **frontend** from **backend** app:

```
Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontend->createUrl('site/index');
// result: http://localhost
```

If you want to generate URL to **backend** from **backend** app:

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('site/index');
// result: http://localhost/admin/site/index
```

If you want to generate URL to **backend** from **frontend** app:

```
Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl('site/index');
// result: http://localhost/admin/site/index
```

If you want to generate URL to **frontend** from **frontend** app:

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('site/index');
// result: http://localhost
```

Comment: that's not working with my code above. i think the problem is with .htaccess file configuration and components in **main** files. They not co-operate...

Comment: I've never used `.htaccess` for such task, so I can't help with that. But you should be more specific - "not working" does not say anything useful.

Comment: @r to be more specific, i can not send request to any other site (in frontend & backend) as site/index or site/login even when definetly "switch off" .htaccess by changing of the file name (filename).

Comment: Did you tried to remove only **root** `.htaccess` (leave `backend/web/.htaccess` and `frontend/web/.htaccess` untouched) and change `baseUrl` of frontend URL managers to `/frontend/web` and `baseUrl` of backend URL managers to `/backend/web`? Does URL `http://localhost/backend/web/site/index` works then?

Comment: yes and i get it : Not Found

The requested URL /backend/index.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at pp.test Port 80

Comment: Links are fully unconnected. nothing works. i just paste your code on a fresh yii2 advanced without .htaccess files and i get 404 error

Comment: I discover that it works with pretty urls disabled (false), is there any chance to set up pretty url ?

Comment: Wait, your `htaccess` is in `backend/web/.htaccess` or `backend/.htaccess`? How does this working URL looks like after disabling pretty URLs?

Comment: backend/.htaccess

Comment: Well, it should be in `backend/web/.htaccess` - move it ant try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600193/yii2-frontend-to-backend-and-backend-to-frontend-controller-config-files-ht/50608905?noredirect=1#comment88229221_50608905

Comment: i'm so close to done that and mark this topic as solved. In few minutes i update the code. trying now set up the pretty url and post fully question.

Comment: added new answer with a short decription.